# Extjs 3.4 reload grid after remove records

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Extjs 3.4 I am removing some records from a `JsonStore` using the `remove()` method. After I save the pending changes by calling the `save()` method. In the db the delete is executed, so records are removed but in the front-end I see the records just removed.

```
gridStore.remove(checkColumn.getSelections());
gridStore.save(); //calling the server.
```

after the `save()` the grid is not reloaded.

How can I reload the grid after the save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After performing a `.remove()` your record *should* be removed from your grid automatically.  But -- if you want to reload the store after your save then just add a `save` `listener` to your store and fire `.load()` :

```
listeners: {
    save: function(store, batch, data) {
        store.load();
    }
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-save

Comment: the remove() don't fires the save event.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reload your data, you must see the changes. I means, put this codes together:

```
Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').getStore().load();
Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').getView().refresh();
```

This it's work for me. I hope that works for you too.